# Useless tag of the day: local

Tags: discussion, tags

The [local](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/local) tag has no usage guidance and it has been applied to questions without any consistent sense (from package management to networking, wherever people think some meaning of the word "local" can be applied). It's useless for categorising anything and should be removed. Thoughts?

Comment: *thinks “right”*

Comment: Just mentioning two possibly relevant tags: [tag:localhost] [tag:remote]

Comment: I'm going to use this tag for all my questions from this point forward unless it's an undeniably remote problem...  **;-)**  (Meaning: *Let's burn the tag!*)

Comment: +10 score is good enough for me. I'm going to remove this a bunch at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag is no longer [local](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/local)ly available.

Comment: +1 for the pun. ;)